# Binding of checkboxes to a field with conditional values

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor app with three checkboxes that are supposed to indicate, if a certain user account should be create, modified or removed.

```
    <input id="CreationCheckbox" type="checkbox" @bind="req.FkRequestType" />

    <input id="ModificationCheckbox" type="checkbox" @bind="req.FkRequestType"/>

    <input id="RemovalCheckbox" type="checkbox" @bind="req.FkRequestType"/>

@code {
    Request req = new Request();
}
```

My model looks like that:

```
 namespace UserManagement.Models
    {
        public partial class Request
        {
            public int PkId { get; set; }
            public int FkRequestType { get; set; }
            public int FkUserId { get; set; }
            public int FkApprover { get; set; }
            public int FkDealer { get; set; }
            public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }

            public virtual Approver FkApproverNavigation { get; set; }
            public virtual DealerCompany FkDealerNavigation { get; set; }
            public virtual RequestTypes Pk { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I want to bind the value 1 for create, 2 for Modify or 3 for removal to the FkRequestType field, depending on which of the checkboxes are activated. With the above code, of course the binding will always result in "1" if one of the checkboxes are ticked.

I tried that but that does not compile:

```
<input id="CreationCheckbox" type="checkbox" @bind="req.FkRequestType == 1 ? 1 : 0" />
<input id="ModificationCheckbox" type="checkbox" @bind="req.FkRequestType == 1 ? 2 : 0" />
<input id="RemovalCheckbox" type="checkbox" @bind="req.FkRequestType == 1 ? 3 : 0" />
```

Comment: Did you consider using a radio instead a checkbox? Also, `@bind` is for "two-way" binding, you should to use here `@onclick="@( ()=>select(1) )"` +  `checked="@(req.FkRequestType == 1)`. Look for [Conditional HTML element attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#conditional-html-element-attributes)

Comment: Agreed for radio instead of checkbox. Otherwise what happens if a user checkbox's multiple checkbox's?

Comment: I have switched to radio buttons, it's really the better option. I already had a function that when you click one checkbox, the other checkboxes will be deactivated. But with the code from dani herrera above, the "select" keyword is not recognized: "the name select does not exist in the current context"